# Designing a centralized file import system

Tags: r

This is an environment design question. I have a number of analysis/forecasting scripts I run each week, and each one relies on a number of files, with most files used by more than one script. I just had to change the name of one of the files, which was a real pain because I had to search through all my scripts and change the path declared in each one.

I would like to use a single .csv master file with file names and their paths, and create a centralized function that takes a list of file names, looks up their file paths, and then imports them all into the global environment. I could use this function in every script I run. Something like:

```
files_needed <- c("File_1", "File_2", "File_4", "File_6")
import_files(files_needed)
```

But then the function would require indirect variable assignment and declaring global variables, which know are frowned upon and I don't even know how to do both at once. I know I can write logic for importing the file path names manually in every script, but there must be a better option, where I can just write the import logic once.

Currently I have a master file that I source at the beginning of every script which loads my most commonly used packages and declares some helper functions I use frequently. I'd love to add this importing functionality in some capacity, but I'm open to solutions that look completely different to what I described. How do people generally solve this problem?

As a final note, many files have another twist, where they incorporate e.g. a date into the file name, so I need to be able to pass additional parameters in order to get the one I need.

Comment: Are these files saved as .Rdata or something else? Would creating a (local) package that contained these files work?  then you would just need to call `data(file1)` and it's at your fingertips.  You could put your helper functions in there too.  That doesn't help with your date issues though.

Comment: These are mostly .csv or .xlsx files that are regularly output by a bunch of different systems, or updated by others on a shared drive. I save them all in a consistent file system. I think a local package with everything would become too large, but it's something I hadn't considered; maybe I could run a routine that constantly checks for new files and purges sufficiently old data. But this seems far from ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Without a worked example this is untested code, but why not just make a list of imported files using those names?

```
files_needed <- c("File_1", "File_2", "File_4", "File_6")
my_imported_files <- 
            setNames( lapply(files_needed, read.csv), paste0(files_needed, "_df") )
```